# Web scraping different names from the same tag

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Hello Guys this is my code:

```
library(rvest)
url_imb <- 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature'
web_page<-read_html(url_imb)

html_text(html_nodes(web_page,xpath='//p[@class=""]//a'))
```

What I need is to extract the Directors Names and put then in a list respecting each movie. The problem is how to extract the right director? Because some movies have more than one directors.

How can I do this and put them in a list?

EDIT: Its look like that the answer is on how I can use "adv_li_dr_0". Right?

Comment: How would output look ? When there are multiple directors for a film what would output look like versus a single director?

Comment: @QHarr `html_text(html_nodes(web_page,xpath='//p[@class=""]//a'))`is a character vector. If you look the 11th movie has 2 directors:  Chris Renaud and Yarrow Cheney. I would like `html_text(html_nodes(web_page,xpath='//p[@class=""]//a'))` to be a list of directors for each movie.

Answer (score 1):

Directors have `href` tag such as `adv_li_dr_0` `adv_li_dr_1` and so on. We can use that to differentiate actors and directors. It is easy to get all the directors on the page using that information however it is tricky to map movies and directors. One way is to get all the nodes with complete movie information and from each node we extract movie name and directors name and create a `tibble`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url_imb <- 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&release_date=2016,2016&title_type=feature'
web_page<-read_html(url_imb)


all_movies <- web_page %>%  html_nodes("div.lister-item-content")
map_df(all_movies,~{
    all_href_tags = .x %>% html_nodes("a")
    directors_name = all_href_tags[all_href_tags %>% 
                     html_attr("href") %>%  
                     grep("adv_li_dr", .)] %>% 
                     html_text()
     movie_name = .x %>% html_nodes("h3 a") %>% html_text()
     tibble(directors_name, movie_name)
})

# A tibble: 116 x 2
#   directors_name     movie_name                             
#   <chr>              <chr>                                  
# 1 David Ayer         Suicide Squad                          
# 2 Babak Najafi       London Has Fallen                      
# 3 Bryan Singer       X-Men: Apocalypse                      
# 4 Tim Miller         Deadpool                               
# 5 M. Night Shyamalan Split                                  
# 6 Gareth Edwards     Rogue One                              
# 7 David Yates        Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them
# 8 Lone Scherfig      Their Finest                           
# 9 Mel Gibson         Hacksaw Ridge                          
#10 Damien Chazelle    La La Land                             
# … with 106 more rows
```

`all_movies` is a basically list of all movies available on the page (100). Using `map_df` we loop through each one of them and create a `tibble` with two columns, one with movie name and other directors name. To get director's name we get text of all the anchor (`<a>`) tags whose `href` attribute has pattern `"adv_li_dr"`. Getting movie name is straight forward.

So for movie with one director (`all_movies[[1]]`) it will return

```
#  directors_name movie_name   
#  <chr>          <chr>        
#1 David Ayer     Suicide Squad
```

and movie with two directors (`all_movies[[11]]`) it will return

```
# directors_name movie_name             
#  <chr>          <chr>                  
#1 Chris Renaud   The Secret Life of Pets
#2 Yarrow Cheney  The Secret Life of Pets
```

So similarly, we get 100 such tibbles which we bind together into one dataframe.

---

To get directors only with `"adv_li_dr_0"` tag, we can do

```
all_tags <- web_page %>% html_nodes("a")
all_tags[all_tags %>%
       html_attr("href") %>%
       grep("adv_li_dr_0", .)] %>%
       html_text()
```

but `adv_li_dr_0` will only get 1st director of the movie and will miss if there are more than 1 directors. To get all the directors, we can do

```
all_tags[all_tags %>%
           html_attr("href") %>%
           grep("adv_li_dr", .)] %>%
 html_text()
```

Comment: could you please explain a little bit more how the code is doing what it is doing (map_df part) ? +

Comment: @QHarr I added some explanation. See if it helps.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.